# PhpStorm Yii2 TestCase error

Tags: php, yii2, phpstorm

I'm configuring PhpStorm 8.0.1 with a basic project of Yii2, but when I run the project it show me:

```
Fatal error: Class 'yii\codeception\TestCase' not found in D:\Progetti\PHP\TestDue\tests\codeception\unit\models\ContactFormTest.php on line 10

Process finished with exit code 255
```

I setted PHP interpreter 5.6.3

anyone with this error?

Comment: 1) Do you have such file at all? 2) If you do -- PHP is unable to find it (fix your bootstrap file -- make sure that autoloader is registered) ?

Comment: 1) Seems that "use Codeception\TestCase\Test;": phpStomr says: "Cannot find declaration to go to" on Codeception... where is located?

Comment: I'm not using Yii2 myself (only played a bit in the past) .. but maybe it is not part of the Yii framework distribution by default and needs to be installed separately? In any case: on my "beta" version of Yii 2 which I currently have (standard package) it is located in `vendor/yiisoft/yii2-codeception/TestCase.php`